# What kind of security risks does nvidia-340 driver have?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, security, nvidia

Quote from https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

> Use of the 340-series driver is strongly discouraged. It is not
> included in stable releases of Debian anymore, has serious unfixable
> security vulnerabilities, and may not be updated for new kernels in a
> timely manner. You are highly recommended to use the built-in Nouveau
> driver if security is a priority.

Quote from [https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142/~/support-timeframes-for-unix-legacy-gpu-releases](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142/%7E/support-timeframes-for-unix-legacy-gpu-releases)

> The Linux 340.* legacy driver series is the last to support the G8x,
> G9x, and GT2xx GPUs, and motherboard chipsets based on them. Support
> for X.Org xserver version 1.20 was added to the 340.* legacy driver
> series with version 340.107, and support for Linux kernels up to Linux
> 5.4 was added with version 340.108. No further releases from the 340.* series are planned.

I see that some patched driver is available for newer kernel, though, in Ubuntu at least, possibly by using PPA. What kind of risks there are in continuing to use nvidia-340?

Comment: GPU drivers security bugs are almost always impossible to exploit unless someone is targeting your specifically and they often require a local user account. TLDR: you're 99.999999% safe even if you're using them.

Answer (score 2):

See [Security Bulletin: NVIDIA GPU display driver contains multiple vulnerabilities in the kernel mode layer handler](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4525) and [Multiple vulnerabilities in NVIDIA GPU Display Driver](https://www.cybersecurity-help.cz/vdb/SB2017080101), things like allowing local unprivileged users access to all memory and escalation of privileges.